# What's the difference between ReadonlyArray and "readonly arr: T[]"?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

See [this playground](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=5.3.3&fileType=.ts&code=JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGITmArlFBvAKGWVzgBMB7EAGwE9kQ4BbCALmQGcwpQBzAbgIBfAgQD0Y5AB4AKhC4A%2BcZJkALYB2QbkAeQDSBUJFiIUqChQCMyQsVKUa9OFCjsAShgd0Agi7i0pdEwcCAVBERgsEAQwYCpOOAA3CEsAChgLdnMrAEobImQEKg4KaggAOmoKXnSLHPDlaTE5RVFG2XkwJQlkACNyAH5kAHdVWgHDcGh4JDQLACZ84mdXZA9yKh8-AKDsXDDhAkjo2PiOJIh52ooshbzbQuLSiqqajIp6w56pZs6ldpaXUa-TIQ1G40mxhmZgsAGYliRPJsnC4shg9hAANoAXQaxxicRACWSsOutwosPuBSKIBKZUq1WunxE31%2BiiAA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGUEKQAIBcBPABxQGNoBLY-AWhXkoDt8B6Y6RAM0Wls4CGAEwD2TeIVrEB0AQFtE%2BXrSKlUGSL2gjokcGAC%2BIA0A&tsconfig=&tokens=false).

```js
interface Feature {
  readonly name: string;
}

// <Test>
// This is OK
interface Foo1 {
  readonly arr: ReadonlyArray<Feature>;
}
function save1(foo: Foo1) {
  console.log(foo);
}
// </Test>


// <Test>
// bad? why?
interface Foo2 {
  arr: ReadonlyArray<Feature>;
}
function save2(foo: Foo2) {
  console.log(foo);
}
// </Test>

// <Test>
// bad? why?
interface Foo3 {
  readonly arr: Feature[];
}
function save3(foo: Foo3) {
  console.log(foo);
}
// </Test>
```

I thought `Foo1`, `Foo2`, and `Foo3` are equivalent, but `@typescript-eslint/prefer-readonly-parameter-types` says otherwise. In summary,

- `Foo1` has both `readonly` and `ReadonlyArray`
- `Foo2` only has `ReadonlyArray`
- `Foo3` only has `readonly`

How are these interfaces different?

Comment: I think your last bullet is supposed to read: `Foo3` only has `readonly`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function `save2`, I'm allowed to do

```js
foo.arr = [];
```

And in `save3`, I'm allowed to do

```js
foo.arr.push({name: 'bar'});
```

None of these operations are allowed in `save1`.

Answer (score 0):

A `ReadonlyArray` is immutable. So the elements in the array can not be modified.

However `readonly arr: Feature[]` means that `arr` can not be redefined, but the items inside the array can be changed.